# How do I upgrade flexmailer?

Tags: upgrade, flexmailer

I have flexmailer 0.2-alpha2 installed. Extension directory says 1.0-beta1 is available, but CiviCRM extension manager does not offer that as an update.

How to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try by downloading the extension from [here](https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.flexmailer/archive/v1.0-beta1.zip) and replacing it with older one in extension directory and then visit the extension page on click on refresh.

Comment: That seems to have worked.